# _vm.myFunction is not defined, in VueJs

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm new in the VueJs world, I have a problem with v-on:click functions.
Here is an example :

**JS & HTML**

```js
var myNav = new Vue({
    el: '#componentNav',
    methods: {
        currentComponentChanger: function (pageName) {
            alert(pageName)
        }
    }
});

var myPage = new Vue({
    el: '#mainComponents',
    data: {
        currentComponent: 'home'
    }
})
```

```html
 <nav id="componentNav">
            <ul>
                <li class="active li"><a class="home active"><button v-on:click="currentComponentChanger('home')">Acceuil</button></a></li>
                <li class="li"><a class="tower"><button v-on:click="currentComponentChanger('tower')">Tower Ascension</button></a></li>
                <li class="li"><a class="faq"><button v-on:click="currentComponentChanger('faq')">F.A.Q.</button></a></li>
                <li class="li"><a class="follow"><button v-on:click="currentComponentChanger('follow')">Nous suivre</button></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Instead of alert, with the currentComponentChanger() function, an error occur and say "**_vm.currentComponentChanger is not defined**". I do not understand why, and I have the same problem with the example of the official doumentation.

Comment: [Works](http://jsfiddle.net/df4Lnuw6/701/). Please provide a reproducible [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'll try, that's weird. It works on JSFiddle, but not on my computer ...